# Multiple autocomplete fields with Material UI in same view

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 autocomplete fields on my view by default, but you can add more fields per click.

Currently I have the problem that every autocomplete field opens every result list of every autocomplete field, because every field uses "open". How do I get it to implement the whole thing dynamically?

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('')
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

 <Autocomplete
        options={props.results.map((option) => option.name)}
        renderOption={(option) => (
            <Typography noWrap>
                {option}
            </Typography>
        )}
        onClose={() => {
            setOpen(false)
        }}
        open={open}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <Paper className={search.root} ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
                <IconButton className={search.iconButton} disabled>
                    <FiberManualRecordIcon color="secondary" />
                </IconButton>
                <InputBase
                    {...params.inputProps}
                    className={search.input}
                    placeholder="Test"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(event: any) => setValue(event.target.value)}
                />
                <IconButton
                    className={search.iconButton}
                    disabled={!value}
                >
                    <SearchIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </Paper>
        )}
    />
```

Comment: do you have only 2 autocomplete components or more?

Comment: @Slim ... Two as a default, but you can add many more per click on a "+"-Button

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already solved this due to the date of this issue. But I'm gonna put here what I did to resolve this problem because I was facing the same issue using FieldArray from Formik.

Material UI documentation sometimes is a little confusing, so try to ignore some stuff in their examples.

Remove the open, onOpen, and onClose props. You just need these props if you want to create some kind of automatic opening/closing mechanic.

Here it's an example of what I was doing and how I solved it.

```
            <Autocomplete
              id={`items.${index}.partNumber`}
              name={`items.${index}.partNumber`}
              freeSolo
              style={{ width: 300 }}
              open={openPartNumber}
              onOpen={() => setOpenPartNumber(true)}
              onClose={() => setOpenPartNumber(false)}
              options={partNumbers}
              clearOnBlur={false}
              getOptionLabel={option => (option.label ? option.label : '')}
              value={item.partNumber}
              inputValue={item.partNumber}
              onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                if (event) {
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.partNumber`, newInputValue);
                  getPartNumberList(newInputValue);
                }
              }}
              onChange={(event, optionSelected, reasson) => {
                if (reasson === 'select-option') {
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.partNumber`, optionSelected.partNumber);
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.vendorNumber`, optionSelected.vendorNumber);
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.description`, optionSelected.description);
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.ncm`, optionSelected.ncm);
                }
              }}
              filterOptions={x => x}
              ...otherPrps...
            />
```

Then I just remove the props open, onOpen and onClose.

```
            <Autocomplete
              id={`items.${index}.partNumber`}
              name={`items.${index}.partNumber`}
              freeSolo
              style={{ width: 300 }}
              options={partNumbers}
              clearOnBlur={false}
              getOptionLabel={option => (option.label ? option.label : '')}
              value={item.partNumber}
              inputValue={item.partNumber}
              onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                if (event) {
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.partNumber`, newInputValue);
                  getPartNumberList(newInputValue);
                }
              }}
              onChange={(event, optionSelected, reasson) => {
                if (reasson === 'select-option') {
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.partNumber`, optionSelected.partNumber);
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.vendorNumber`, optionSelected.vendorNumber);
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.description`, optionSelected.description);
                  setFieldValue(`items.${index}.ncm`, optionSelected.ncm);
                }
              }}
              filterOptions={x => x}
              ...otherPrps...
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want automatic opening/closing mechanics to exist. One suggestion is to control open starting from an array.

In the onOpen and onClose props, your callback must control an array by adding and removing the AutoComplete ID and in open just check the existence of this ID inside the array with array.includes(index).

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('')
//const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

const [inputsOpen, setInputsOpen] = useState([])

    function automatedOpening(id) {
    if (id && inputsOpen.length === 0) {
      setInputsOpen([...inputsOpen, id]);
    } 
  }
// lenght must be zero to ensure that no other autocompletes are open and will be true on the Open prop


  function automatedClosing(id) {
        if (id && inputsOpen.length !== 0) {
          setInputsOpen(inputsOpen.filter(item => item !== id));
        } 
      }

 <Autocomplete
        options={props.results.map((option) => option.name)}
        renderOption={(option) => (
            <Typography noWrap>
                {option}
            </Typography>
        )}
        onClose={(e) => automatedClosing(e.id)}
        onOpen={(e) => automatedClosing(e.id)}
        open={inputsOpen.includs(id)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <Paper className={search.root} ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
                <IconButton className={search.iconButton} disabled>
                    <FiberManualRecordIcon color="secondary" />
                </IconButton>
                <InputBase
                    {...params.inputProps}
                    className={search.input}
                    placeholder="Test"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(event: any) => setValue(event.target.value)}
                />
                <IconButton
                    className={search.iconButton}
                    disabled={!value}
                >
                    <SearchIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </Paper>
        )}
    />
```

you'll probably need to find a way to make the id/index available to the callbacks, but it's open to what you think is best